# Binding Getters and Setters with a Macro

Tags: macros, clojure, getter-setter

Most of my application state is stored in a large complex map.  For the purposes of this question, I will use a simple structure:

```
(def data
  {:a 1
   :b {:c {:d 3}}})
```

I have a large number of functions which all follow the same pattern:

```
(defn update-map
  [my-map val]
  (let [a (:a my-map)
        d (-> my-map :b :c :d)]
    (assoc-in
      (assoc my-map :a (+ a val))
      [:b :c :d] (+ d val))))
```

I retrieve one or more values from the map, perform some calculations, and create a new map with updated values.  There are two problems with this approach:

- I have a lot of repetitive let bindings across different function definitions
- If the schema of the map changes, I will have a lot of code to refactor

I've written a macro to reduce the boilerplate code required to define these functions.  It works by looking up predefined getter and setter functions, and automatically generating a let block:

```
(def getters
  {'a #(:a %)
   'd #(-> % :b :c :d)})

(def setters
  {'a #(assoc % :a %2)
   'd #(assoc-in % [:b :c :d] %2)})

(defmacro def-map-fn
  [name [& args] [& fields] & code]
  (let [my-map 'my-map
        lookup #(reduce % [] fields)
        getter-funcs (lookup #(conj % %2 (list (getters %2) my-map)))
        setter-funcs (lookup #(conj % (symbol (str "update-" %2)) (setters %2)))]
    `(defn ~name [~my-map ~@args]
       (let [~@getter-funcs ~@setter-funcs]              
         ~@code))))
```

I can now define my functions more elegantly:

```
(def-map-fn update-map
  [val] ; normal function parameters
  [a d] ; fields from the map I will be using
  (update-d
    (update-a my-map (+ a val))
    (+ d val)))
```

When expanded, it will produce a function definition looking something like this:

```
(defn update-map
  [my-map val]
  (let [a (#(:a %) my-map)
        d (#(-> % :b :c :d) my-map)
        update-a #(assoc % :a %2)
        update-d #(assoc-in % [:b :c :d] %2)]
    (update-d
      (update-a my-map (+ a val))
      (+ d val))))
```

One thing that is nagging me about my macro is that it is not intuitive to the programmer that the `my-map` function parameter is available for use within the function body.

Is this a good use of macros, or should I be using a different approach entirely (like dynamic var bindings)?

Comment: Just a quick comment - consider using `(update-in my-map [:b :c :d] + val)` instead of `assoc-in`. This might at least allow you to avoid a `let` binding.

Comment: @Alex I agree with you that in this example `update-in` is more elegant than `assoc-in`.  However, if I use a macro to automatically retrieve setter functions, I think I need to use the assoc style consistently throughout all the fields, since I can't always think about the new value as a function of the old value.

Comment: Understood. In this particular case, my personal preference would be to avoid the use of macros, as they aren't composable. For instance, what happens when you want to use a getter or setter function outside of a function being defined by `def-map-fn`?

Comment: @Alex definitely a valid point.  What approach would you take then?  I just don't like writing repetitive let bindings all the time.  Dynamic var bindings seem like an option, but thats not very functional.

Comment: `(fn [x] (-> data (update-in [:a] + x) (update-in [:b :c :d] + x)))` Can you show us an example of the problem where using `get-in`, `update-in`, and `assoc-in` wouldn't just solve the problem? Note, re comment, `(update-in [keys] (constantly value))` is the same as `(assoc-in [keys] value)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this situation, my preference is to avoid the use of macros. They often obfuscate code, but more importantly they aren't composable. An ideal solution here would allow you to use the getter and setter functions outside of functions being defined in `def-map-fn`. I'd stick with regular functions and data as much as possible.

To begin with, you're concerned about having to rewrite a bunch of code if your schema changes. Fair enough. To address that, I'd start with a data representation of your map's schema. See [Prismatic schema](https://github.com/Prismatic/schema) for a full-featured schema library for Clojure, but for now something along these lines should do:

```
(def my-schema
  {:a :int
   :b {:c {:d :int}}})
```

From this, you can compute the paths for all the properties in your schema:

```
(defn paths [m]
  (mapcat (fn [[k v]]
            (conj (if (map? v)
                    (map (partial apply vector k) (paths v)))
                  [k]))
          m))

(def property-paths
  (into {} (for [path (paths my-schema)] [(last path) path])))
```

Now, to get or set a property, you can look up its path and use that in conjunction with `get-in`, `update-in`, etc. as appropriate:

```
(let [d (get-in my-map (property-paths :d))]
  ;; Do something with d.
  )
```

If you get tired of always calling `get-in`, `assoc-in`, etc., then you can pretty easily generate a bunch of getter functions:

```
(doseq [[p path] property-paths]
  (eval `(defn ~(symbol (str "get-" (name p)))
           [m#] (get-in m# ~path))))

(doseq [[p path] property-paths]
  (eval `(defn ~(symbol (str "set-" (name p)))
           [m# v#] (assoc-in m# ~path v#))))

(doseq [[p path] property-paths]
  (eval `(defn ~(symbol (str "update-" (name p)))
           [m# tail#] (apply update-in m# ~path #tail))))
```

Now you have your `get-a`, `set-a`, `update-a` functions available everywhere in your code, without having to call into some uber-macro to set up the bindings for you. For instance:

```
(let [a (get-a my-map)]
  (-> my-map
      (set-a 42)
      (update-d + a)))
```

If you really find setting up the above `let` binding tedious, you could even write a `with-properties` macro that accepts a map and a list of property names and executes the body in a context that binds values for those names. But I probably wouldn't bother.

Advantages of this approach include:

1. It's schema-driven, so the schema is defined in one central place and used to generate other code as needed.
2. It prefers pure functions over macros, so code is more re-usable and composable.
3. It's an incremental approach that allows your application to grow more naturally. Rather than starting with an uber-macro that tries to anticipate all possible features you might want, you start with data and functions and sprinkle in macros to alleviate some of the repetitiveness as you see usage patterns emerge.

Answer (score 5):

You could perhaps use lenses; the getters and setters then become composable functions. Have a look [here](https://gist.github.com/ctford/15df66f029f70b986121) or [here](https://github.com/cark/data.lenses/blob/master/example/src/example/core.clj).

Following the first link you can set up the lens as follows:

```
; We only need three fns that know the structure of a lens.
(defn lens [focus fmap] {:focus focus :fmap fmap})
(defn view [x {:keys [focus]}] (focus x))
(defn update [x {:keys [fmap]} f] (fmap f x))

; The identity lens.
(defn fapply [f x] (f x))
(def id (lens identity fapply))

; Setting can be easily defined in terms of update.
(defn put [x l value] (update x l (constantly value)))

(-> 3 (view id))
; 3
(-> 3 (update id inc))
; 4
(-> 3 (put id 7))
; 7

; in makes it easy to define lenses based on paths.
(defn in [path]
  (lens
    (fn [x] (get-in x path))
    (fn [f x] (update-in x path f))))

(-> {:value 3} (view (in [:value])))
; 3
(-> {:value 3} (update (in [:value]) inc))
; {:value 4}
(-> {:value 3} (put (in [:value]) 7))
; {:value 7}
```

You can see form the above the the lens can be adapted to use get/set methods (such as get-in/update-in) based on the data structure you are working with. The real power of lenses which seems to also be what you are after is that you can compose them. In the same example the composition function can be defined as follows:

```
(defn combine [outer inner]
  (lens
    (fn [x] (-> x (view outer) (view inner)))
    (fn [f x] (update x outer #(update % inner f)))))

(defn => [& lenses] (reduce combine lenses))
```

The => function can now be used to combine any arbitrary lenses such as:

```
(-> {:new {:value 3}} (view (=> (in [:new]) (in [:value]))))
; 3
(-> {:new {:value 3}} (update (=> (in [:new]) (in [:value])) inc))
; {:new {:value 4}}
(-> {:new {:value 3}} (put (=> (in [:new]) (in [:value])) 7))
; {:new {:value 7}}
```

The fact that (in [:new]) is just a function means that you could, for example, store it and manipulate it in various ways. For example, it would be possible to walk your nested map structure and create the lens functions which correspond to accessing the value at each level in the nested map and then at the end compose these functions together to create your getter/setter api. With this set up, your lenses could automatically adapt to any changes in your schema.

The ability to compose lenses can also make it easy to interact with the nodes of your nested map. For example, if you were to ever change the node from an atom to a list, you could simply add a new lens to work with it as follows:

```
(def each (lens seq map))

(-> {:values [3 4 5]} (view   (=> (in [:values]) each)))
; (3 4 5)
(-> {:values [3 4 5]} (update (=> (in [:values]) each) inc))
; {:values (4 5 6)}
(-> {:values [3 4 5]} (put    (=> (in [:values]) each) 7))
; {:values (7 7 7)}
```

I highly recommend looking at the full [gist](https://gist.github.com/ctford/15df66f029f70b986121) to see more examples of what you can do with lenses.

Comment: Could you please expand your answer some? StackOverflow frowns on "link-only" answers.

Comment: I selectively plagiarised the gist to show how it relates to the question. It's worth looking at the full gist however to see more ways the lenses can be used - especially around filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use `update-in`?

```
(defn update-map [my-map val]
  (-> my-map
      (update-in [:a] + val)
      (update-in [:b :c :d] + val)))
```

Comment: In the example I gave that would work, but in the actual code I am defining about 50 functions following this pattern and update-in won't work for many of them.